# Getting socket is closed error on using HttpResponse Object

Tags: java, sockets, http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a httpClient function which returns an HttpResponse object to the calling function.

```
public HttpResponse postRequest(String uri, String body) throws IOException {
        HttpResponse response;
        String url = baseUrl + uri;
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .build()) {
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setEntity(new StringEntity(body));
            post.setHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, authorization);
            post.setHeader(CONTENTTYPE_HEADER, APPLICATION_JSON);
            post.setHeader(ACCEPT_HEADER, APPLICATION_JSON);

            response = httpClient.execute(post);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Caught an exception" + e.getMessage().toString());
            logger.error("Caught an exception" + e.getMessage().toString());
            throw e;
        }
        return response;
    }
```

In my calling function I call, `HttpResponse response = httpRequest.postRequest(url,body);` (where httpRequest is an object for the class which contains the function

When I try to parse the contents of the received the response through

```
String responseString = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity()
                    .getContent(), "UTF-8");
```

I get an error Socket is closed.

How do I use the contents of HttpResponse once the connection is closed?

Answer (score 0):

Your try-with-resources statement is closing the entire client. You don't want that. Remove it. You want the close to happen when the caller closes the response you're returning.

Comment: Could you give me an example. I didn't follow you